# window.location.href vs redirect utility of react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I have webapp written using React and React Router.

Are there any pros/cons of using window.location.href to redirect vs using the  component provided via react-router?

Comment: `window.location.href` will reload the browser entirely, but using `history.push`, `history.replace` or the `Link` component will not result in a browser refresh.

Answer (score 13):

Use `history.push('/page-name')` if you don't want the browser window to be reloaded, or window.location.href if you want to reload it. Usually when using the React Router the default behavior is using the history.push (`this.props.history.push('/page-name'`) to be more specific, as the rest of the navigation through the application is already using React Route's `<Link>`, which has the same effect.

Comment: Hi @okapoor. Did my anwser solved your problem? Hope you can select it as a response :)

Answer (score 1):

React-Router provides an interface for changing the URL either by modifying [`history`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history) or by using a [Redirect component](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect).

The React-Router interface is much more expressive than just manipulating `window.location.href`. I think the main pro of using React-Router is the added functionality, abstraction, and cleaner interface. Don't know that there are any real performance differences.