# Can't POST and redirect at the same time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect

If I comment out `document.location.href = 'https://www.mywebsite.ca/thankyou'` the `POST` works.
If I uncomment it, the redirect works, but the `POST` doesn't fire.

I am using using React and I don't need the response data, I just need to send (form) data. Please help, thanks!

```
fetch(
  "https://mycloudservice.com/myendpoint",
  {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    headers: { "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
  }
)
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((json) => console.log('complete'))
.then(
  //document.location.href = 'https://www.mywebsite.ca/thankyou'
);
```

Comment: Shouldn't the last one be a function too? `.then(() => { document.location.href = 'something' })`

Comment: @Aioros Using your code the redirect doesn't happen at all, just tested. Everything inside `.then();` is executed how it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unsure if this will fix the issue, but...

When using browserHistory for React-router, it's best to use the following in order to stop the browser from refreshing, and your app reloading.

Instead try this:

**Class Component:**

```
this.props.history.push("/path");
```

**Functional Component:**

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

function Foo() {
  let history = useHistory();

  function handleFetch() {
    fetch("https://mycloudservice.com/myendpoint", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      headers: { "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" }
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => console.log("complete"))
      .then(()=>history.push("/path"));
  }

  return (
    //Anything
  );
}
```

take a look at this post:
[window.location.href vs redirect utility of react-router-dom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51713513/window-location-href-vs-redirect-utility-of-react-router-dom)

Comment: I added in all the functional component code, and no redirect happens. Do I also need to implement the class component somewhere? (Sorry, I'm brand new to React).

Comment: No, it's one or the other depending on if your component is a class or functional component. Also, you need to then call the function "handleFetch" somehow. Or put the contents of handleFetch in a useEffect hook if you want it to fire when the component renders.

Comment: Alright I got it working, thakyou! I Actually tried this the other day but on a error lazily just did `document.location.href =` instead. There is one problem in your code (for my setup atleast) which is `useHistory()` wouldn't work if defined in my function, it had to be defined in the root of my component, then it finally worked! Thanks!